# When i am using ng-repeat the data getting printed with newline. How can i remove the newline from data while printing

Tags: angularjs

When i am using ng-repeat the data getting printed with newline. How can i remove the newline from data while printing.

```
 <div ng-repeat  = "x in names1">
                    {{x.status}}
            </div>
```

Comment: change div tag to span

Comment: thanks it is working fine now @venkat

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`span`** instead of **`div`**, which would display in one line

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.names = ['AAA','BBB','CCC'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app= "testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="friend in names">
  {{friend}}
</span>
</body>
```